# Avoid same try catch blocks in Java

Tags: java, json, exception, org.json

I am developing a project which involves JSON manipulation in Java using [JSON API](http://www.json.org/javadoc/). There are many places where I need to read values from JSON file. The API provides checked exceptions for the same. Everytime I use the API to read JSON values, I am forced to write try catch block. As a result, there is a large number of try catch blocks. It makes the code look messy.

```
    String Content = "";
    try {
        read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Data.json"));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("File Not found");
    }

    try {
        while((line = read.readLine() ) != null) { 
            Content = Content+line;     
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        ResponseArr = new JSONArray( Content );
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        ResponseObj = ResponseArr.getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("childrens");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        StoreResponse = ResponseArr.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("childrens");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Is there any way to avoid this ?A single try catch block would not suffice and the statements are not dependent. Each read statement requires a separate try catch block as I have to log the details of places while catching the exception. Can I invoke a common method whenever I have a code to read JSON data, like sending the code as a paramater to a method which would take care of the exception  handling or some other way round ?

Comment: Why catch these exceptions at all? Just let them bubble up.

Comment: You could also have one big try/catch block with everything inside.

Comment: You should not have separate try/catch like this... Anyway if your first try fails, all the others are bound to fail too since `read` would be null...

Answer (score 1):

Since (all?) the subsequent statements are dependent on the previous it makes no sense having that many try/catch blocks. I would rather put the code inside one try/catch and handle the exceptions by type

Pseudo-code:

```
 String Content = "";
    try {
        read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Data.json"));
        while((line = read.readLine() ) != null) { 
            Content = Content+line;     
        }
        ResponseArr = new JSONArray( Content );
        ResponseObj = ResponseArr.getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("childrens");
    } catch (JSONException e) {       
        e.printStackTrace();    
    } catch(FileNotFoundException)
            System.out.println("File Not found");
    }
    // and so on
```

As some are suggesting, you might want to let all these exceptions bubble up (not catching them) since you're not doing anything meaningful when catching them. However, I think that depends on the calling context.

Comment: I would rather have separate `catch` blocks. Don't rely on `instanceOf`, it can cause chaos in case of *inheritance*

Comment: The premise is correct but your catch statement is no good, before I downvote I would like to give you the opportunity to fix it. You should catch those in their own `catch` block.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar: Well, inheritence will work just the same way in multiple catch blocks.

Comment: @Thilo - Right. I was just making a general note about not relying in `instanceOf` too much in situations like this. Of course if the ordering of catch blocks is wrong, the OP will get an *Unreachable code* compiler error :)

Comment: I think the main problem is it catches all `Exception` and doesnt do something for all `Exception`, Undoubtedly this will lead to OP posting a question about why his code isnt working because it swallowed a NPE with no error message.

Comment: I am with @ug_, don't catch these exceptions at all, let them bubble up. Only catch exceptions when you can really do something about them.

Comment: @Fontanka16 The subsequent statements are not always dependent on the previous statement. I have to log each time the the code fails to fetch data. And also ,JSON data file is a dynamic one.

Comment: But i cannot see that from your example. Wich statement is not dependant on the previous? @SmallStep

Comment: @Fontanka16 Updated the question. The code goes like that. It is dependant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling all exceptions in the same way, why not combine them in one try/ catch clause
for example like this :

```
try {
        while((line = read.readLine() ) != null) { 
            Content = Content+line;     
        }
       ResponseArr = new JSONArray( Content );
       ResponseObj = ResponseArr.getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("childrens");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: and that also allows you to declare `content` and `responseArr` locally inside that scope.

Comment: catch (Exception e) is not a good idea in the most cases. Try to be more specific since your statement will also catch RuntimeExceptions

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
String Content = "";
try {
    read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Data.json"));
       while((line = read.readLine() ) != null) { 
        Content = Content+line;     
      }
      ResponseArr = new JSONArray( Content );
      ResponseObj = ResponseArr.getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("childrens");
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("File Not found");
    }
```